# Distance from point to line

Tags: plotting, geometry

I'm a newbie with Mathematica and I managed to draw a line and a point in 3D on a graph

```
Q = Graphics3D[Point[{50, 10, 25}]];
line = ParametricPlot3D[{5 + t, 5 + t, 5 + t}, {t, 0, 100}];
Show[Q, line]
```

not sure if I wrote the parametric line command correctly (I wanted to draw a $P(t) = P + Vt$ parametric line where $P$ is the starting point (5;5;5) and $V$ a unit vector (1;1;1)).

Now I would like to calculate the distance between the point Q and the line. I know how to do this in linear algebra ($d = ||(Q-P)-\frac{(Q-P)\cdot V}{||v||^2} V||$), but I'm unsure on how to do this. Is there a pre-defined function in mathematica to get the distance from a point to a line?

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113896/seeing-coordinates-in-graphics3d/113962#113962) is related. There is also an implementation of the formula in the question.

Comment: Check out `RegionDistance`

Comment: You can also write your parametric formula `{5, 5, 5} + t {1, 1, 1}`.  See also [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20085) -- there are many ways to approach this problem, and many functions one might use (`Norm`, `EuclideanDistance`, `Dot`, `Projection`,...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `RegionNearest`

```
pt = {50, 10, 25};
line = Line[Table[{5 + t, 5 + t, 5 + t}, {t, 0, 100}]];
npt = RegionNearest[line, pt];
Graphics3D[{line, Blue, Line[{pt, npt}], Red, Point[{pt, npt}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
p = {50, 10, 25};
l = InfiniteLine[{5, 5, 5}, {1, 1, 1}];

RegionDistance[l, p]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a pre-defined function in *Mathematica* to get the distance from a point to a line?

There isn't one, but thankfully for you, both `EuclideanDistance[]` and `Projection[]` are built-in:

```
PointLineDistance[pt_, {s1_, s2_}] :=
                  With[{tp = s1 - pt}, EuclideanDistance[tp, Projection[tp, s2 - s1]]]
```

Thus,

```
PointLineDistance[{50, 10, 25}, {{5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5} + {1, 1, 1}}]
   35 Sqrt[2/3]
```